# Error while getting current location on maps

Tags: iphone, maps

I am new to iphone development.I am creating a map application.I have used following code in header file

```
@interface BrusMapSubviewcontroller : UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
 IBOutlet UIButton *location;
IBOutlet UIButton *backtocampus;
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *location;
@property(retain,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *backtocampus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


-(IBAction) gosearch : (id) sender;
-(IBAction) backtocampus: (id)sender;
```

In the implementation class

```
 -(IBAction) gosearch : (id) sender{
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; 

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"inside go search");

}
  -(IBAction) backtocampus: (id)sender{

 MKCoordinateRegion region;
 region.center.latitude=41.825672;
 region.center.longitude=-71.402695;
 region.span.latitudeDelta=0.001551;
 region.span.longitudeDelta=0.005493;
mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
 mapView.region=region;

NSLog(@"inside back to campus");
}

- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
 fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
 NSLog(@"inside update");
  printf("\n Latitude = %s\n Longitude = %s",[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%.7f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude]);

 }

- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
printf("\nerror");
 }
```

When i run in simulator "inside update" is printed in console and long and lat values.But if i run in ipod "inside go search" is alone printed in console.Why there is difference output in simulator and device.Thanks.

Comment: You said "ipod", did you mean an iPod Touch or iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator is preset to a location in California (~37.3, -122.0) , so when you start location manager on the simulator you get a call to [didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:) right away with the preset location.  That's the only location you'll ever get from the simulator.

On an iPhone it could take anywhere from a couple seconds to several minutes before it has a valid GPS location so it may take some time before you see the "inside update" message or the "error" message.  But you should get one or the other eventually.

You can also change the [distanceFilter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter) and [desiredAccuracy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy) to control how often you get location updates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, the reason for the difference from simulator to device is; the simulator is preset to Apple in CA location.  So when you run the app on the device you will get your current location and when you run the app on the simulator you will get Apple in CA location.

Comment: my simulator is not showing the apple in ca location, it just printing the coordinates in console.to load that place in maps what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The iPod doesn't embedded the GPS. So I suppose that it may cause this dysfunction.